# If I have to calculate or retrieve the cost per each deployment or an App in Azure AKS, What's the best approach?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

How do I do chargeback for shared Kubernetes clusters on Azure? Say there are 10 departments/customers using a cluster split by namespaces, How do I bill them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look on [kubecost](https://github.com/kubecost).

> Kubecost models give teams visibility into current and historical Kubernetes spend and resource allocation. These models provide cost transparency in Kubernetes environments that support multiple applications, teams, departments, etc.

`Kubecost` enables you to get:

- Real-time cost allocations by all key k8s concepts,
- Cost allocation by configurable labels to measure spend by owner,
  team, department, product, etc.
- Dynamic asset pricing enabled by integrations with AWS and GCP
  billing APIs, estimates available for Azure
- Cost allocation metrics for CPU, GPU, memory, and storage
- Out of cluster cloud costs tied back to owner
- You can also export billing data back to Prometheus for further
  analysis

Check also [this](https://karlstoney.com/2018/07/07/managing-your-costs-on-kubernetes/) article. It shows a way for checking costs using Grafana.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use tags. That would make it easier for you to filter down the usage and billing as well.

Tags is the easiest and most efficient way to segregate resources.